# ESLint code format in Vue

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I created a project with npm and vuejs/vue-cli.

I imported the ESLint extension.

I have eslint entries in my `package.json` file.

Now when I format my code (right-click, Format Code), it completely disfigures my code.

**What do I have to do to get vscode to format according to the ESLint rules?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

But on the website, ESLint complains that everything is not formatted correctly, and so it is obviously installed and running in some sense:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1) First, you need to install the ESLint extension in the VS code.

This extension uses the ESLint library.If you haven't installed ESLint either locally or globally do so by running

```
npm install eslint //For a local install
 or 
npm install -g eslint //For a global install.
```

2) Then, open Setting.json file in VS code. by
   File-> Preferences->Settings.

3) Add following setting.

```
 {
    "eslint.enable": true,
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "eslint.run": "onType",
    "eslint.options": {
        "extensions": [".js",".vue"]
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        { "language": "vue", "autoFix": true }
    ]
}
```

4) Now, check your vue file.It will start showing linting error.If not, restart the VS code.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem before. 
I resolved it by installing eslint using npm install locally(it can be installed globally), then run "eslint --init", restart vscode.
Hope this help you.

Comment: I executed `npm install eslint`, then `eslint --init`, but it gave the error that it could not find `eslint` as a name of a Cmdlet, function or script file.

Comment: try clean cache and then `npm install eslint --save-dev`, 'eslint --int`, you also can install globally use sudo.

Comment: After `npm install -g eslint` then `eslint --init` ran and I answered configuration questions. I restared VS Code but it still doesn't format the code. Is there some other initiation or setup I have to do?

Comment: In my settings `"eslint.enable": true,` so it should be working, shouldn't it?

Comment: And how do I clean the cache? When I type CTRL-P and "cache" it doesn't bring up any commands.

Comment: But on the website, ESLint complains that everything is not formatted correctly, and so it is obviously installed and running in some sense (see added screenshot above).

Comment: just at the root of project then `npm cache clean', yes, if eslint has any output, it worked. So your eslint already worked. if any error, maybe eslint has some rules conflicts with vscode formatter.

Comment: if you have any other formatted plugins, you'd better to disable it